# Recorrer con un for en VueJS

Tags: nodejs, firebase, vue.js, electron, bootstrap-vue

Estimados estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con electronjs y vuejs, pero tengo un problema. Estoy usando vuetify y no puedo mostrar los datos de firebase, solamente me pasa con vuetify....ahora lo explico.

```
<v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          label="Standard"
        ></v-select>
      </v-flex>
```

Y en Vuejs:

```
items:function(){

    return this.localidad 
/*localidad es la conexion a firebase.localidad.descripcion*/

}
```

localidad esta declarada como atributo en el coponente:

```
let localidad = mdb.ref('localidad').child('pcia_descripcion');
let pais = mdb.ref('pais');
let provincia = mdb.ref('provincia');

new Vue({
    el: '#ausuario',
    firebase: function () {
        return {
            tipodentidad: tidenti,
            localidad: localidad,
            pais: pais,
            provincia: provincia
        }
    },
```

Mi pregunta es: como hago para mostrar los datos de localidad en el dropdown (select) con `v-bind:items="localidad"`. Creo que lo mejor seria recorrer con for el array del componente dentro de la propiedad "localidad", pero no se como hacerlo, busque informacion y no econtre.

Comment: Vos tenes items como una funcion, pero si es un array, deberias pasarselo directamente, y el componente va a hacer el for directamente.

Comment: Asi me decis: `items:[
            this.localidad
        ],` . Lo acabo de cambiar y me dice `undefined`

Comment: Probaste con `items: "items()"`?

Comment: Javier  `items: (
            this.localidades
        ),` . Tampoco me entrega ningun dato, la verdad que no entiendo como haces para mostrar datos en un dropdown de vuetify. He llamarlo de muchas formas pero ninguna me entrega algun dato

Comment: Creo que te falta estudiar un poco mas como trabaja VUE y sus componentes. Lo que necesita ese componente, es un array de items. en ninguno de los casos le estas pasando un array de datos. localidad, en ese caso, solo tiene una localidad. si pones :items="localidad" te va aparecer un solo item, y no la lista completa de localidades. Vos que es lo que queres hacer? porque a ese modelo, le falta un array con todas las localidades.

Comment: Salvo que localidad, la variable y no la propiedad (yo no les pondria el mismo nombre nunca) se llene con un array. Estas usando la herramienta del navegador para ver el contenido de tus propiedadeS?

Comment: gbianchi, si puede ser que me falta saber mas sobre VUE, soy nuevo con el. No estoy confundiendo la variable con la propiedad. Localidad es la variable donde almaceno la "url" a localidad en Firebase. Tambien cambie el nombre de la propiedad a `localidades` y quedaria `localidades:localidad`. Creo que el problema esta en que no me esta mostrando ningun dato, por que fuese el problema que me mostrara un solo dato creo que lo solucionaria pronto. Me puedes mostrar en codigo como harias tu ?

Comment: Podrías replicar tu ejemplo en codepen?

Answer (score 1):

Les respondo a todos... la solucion estaba aqui:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3862

```
<v-select
:items="items"
v-model="select"
item-text="name"
item-value="id"
return-object
></v-select>
```

Comment: Márcala como aceptada para que la buena salud del sitio se mantenga, gracias por tu colaboración :D